# Compiling w/glib2.0 on Ubuntu, I get g_thread_supported assertion failed

Tags: multithreading, glib

I thought GNU threads would be available when I install GLib, but maybe something is wrong? Here is how I installed glib on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

When I run my code, it calls g_thread_pool_create, and glib says:

```
(process:22232): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_thread_pool_new: assertion `g_thread_supported ()' failed
```

Mind you my code definitely compiles and links just fine. It's just the assertion that's failing when I call `g_thread_pool_new`, and subsequently when I call `g_thread_pool_push`.

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered please?

Answer (score 2):

Did you call `g_thread_init(NULL)` to initialize the thread subsystem?

Comment: In /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.a, there's no function by that name.

Comment: Aah, it turned out to be in libgthread. Problem solved, thanks.